# Issue returning header byte from Python to Unity

Tags: python, c#

I'm newbie in Python, so probably I'm wrong something. Be patient.

I send JSON data from Python to Unity app.
In unity I use NetworkStream and in Python I send a header before send the JSON data to receive the real buffer of data to get.
The first time I receive this byte array header: 50,57,49,56,50 and the JSON data sent after are all correct.
The second time I receive this byte array header: 53,53,52,49,123 and the Int32.Parse(Encoding.Default.GetString(header) go in exception.

I don't understand why, can you help me?
Thanks.

Here the code:

**Python**:

```
datastr = {'id': objectIDCurrent, 'contour': boxArray, 'measureA': dimA, 'measureB': dimB, 'image': image}               
data = json.dumps(datastr)
sdata = str(data)
datas = json.dumps(sdata)
json_object = json.loads(datas)                
fileSize = len(json_object)
conn.send(str(fileSize).encode())
conn.sendall(json_object.encode())
```

**C#** (relevant code about issue):

```
...
NetworkStream s;
s = TcpClient.GetStream();
header = new byte[5];
s.Read(header, 0, header.Length);
fileSize = Int32.Parse(Encoding.Default.GetString(header));
```

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ . Think carefully about what `json.dumps`, `json.loads` and `str.encode` do. Try to check the type and value of each intermediate value in the Python code, and make sure they are what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Python code is... wonky. For one, you're calculating the number of keys in the dict and you're not padding the length to 5 bytes.

Assuming what you want is to send a JSON blob over the socket with an ASCII length header, you'll want

```
data = {'id': ...}  # Some JSONable object
json_data = json.dumps(data).encode("UTF-8")
data_len = len(json_data)
assert data_len <= 99999  # we can't represent larger length with this encoding scheme
conn.sendall(("%05d" % data_len).encode("UTF-8"))
conn.sendall(json_data)
```

Then on the receiving side,

```
var s = TcpClient.GetStream();
var header = new byte[5];
s.Read(header, 0, header.Length);
var size = Int32.Parse(Encoding.Default.GetString(header));
var data = new byte[size];
s.Read(data, 0, size);
```

should do.

However, as the `assert` in the Python code says, this scheme has the shortcoming that 99999 bytes is the largest blob you can send – I'd suggest sending the length as a 32-bit unsigned integer (that is, 4 binary bytes):

```
import struct
# ...
conn.sendall(struct.pack("<I", data_len))  # little-endian
conn.sendall(json_data)
```

and

```
var header = new byte[4];
s.Read(header, 0, 4);
var size = BitConverter.ToUInt32(header);
// ...
```

Comment: Many thanks for the code and your clarifications. I edited my codes and now C# side I get the data correctly, but Python side that assertion about 99999 has stopped the loop. Can how manage this? Because that script run a infinite loop to send data continuosly. Thanks again

Comment: UPDATE: Unity side the data get correctly until python script return exception about that assert.

Comment: Well, you're attempting to send a blob that's too big for this protocol. The assert is there to protect you from errors stemming from that.

Comment: @Kafar I expanded on the binary header idea for larger data. If you use that, you can remove the assert (or change it to about 4 gigabytes).

Comment: Many thanks again, I edited the codes. Now Python script run but the C# code enter in the read and it not exit until reach the FileSize freezing the UI.  Here the code:
~~~~
int increment = 0;
while (recieved < fileSize)
{
   byte[] dataReceived = new byte[fileSize];
   increment = s.Read(dataReceived, 0, dataReceived.Length);
   recieved += increment;
   ms.Write(dataReceived.Take(increment).ToArray(), 0, increment);
}

myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.GetBuffer()));
~~~~

Comment: @Kafar It's very hard to help with code in a comment. Please ask a new question with your new, revised code (and link it here). In the meantime, if this helped you, mark it as accepted...

Comment: I marked your answer. But I can't post a new question today due my lower account. I'll post tomorrow only, but if you can read however that code could be really important for me. Thanks

Comment: Add a print/debug.print/... to make sure the `fileSize` seems sane. That aside, you can just do `byte[] buffer = new byte[65535]; var ms = new MemoryStream(); while (ms.Length < fileSize) { var nRead = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); ms.Write(buffer, 0, nRead); }` – that is, use the memory stream's length instead of having a separate `received` variable.

Comment: Hi, I modified the code following your tips. Now the data incoming good but after "n" times the loop break because receive a json string with an entire structure of data with open/close bracket PLUS the next structure of data with open bracket, some data and in the "image:" some data and many of these "\0" and unless the close bracket.. And the json parser obviously breaks. Why and what can I do? Thanks

Comment: From that description, no, I can't really tell what's wrong. Maybe ask another question with the revised code...

Comment: I asked a new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66778354/issue-returning-data-from-python-to-unity